# Is there a way to perform atomic CMake build?

Tags: build, makefile, cmake, build-process

I'm considering reimplementing our build system (currently based on `GNU Make`) in `CMake`.

Disclaimer: this is more of a theoretical and "best practices" question. I don't know `CMake` in-depth. Also, please feel free to migrate the question to programmers if it's more on-topic there.

As far as I understand, the standard workflow for `CMake` is

```
cmake .
make
```

I suspect there may be problems of de-synchronization of `CMake` files and Makefiles.

So, during usual development process you're supposed to run `make` to avoid unnecessary rebuilds of `CMakeCache` and `Makefiles` and generally make the process more straight-forward. But then, if you add, say, a new source file to `CMakeLists` and run `make`, it'll be using old `CMakeCache` and `Makefiles` and will not regenerate them automatically. I think it may cause major problems when used at scale, since in case something is not building as it should, you'll have to try to perform `make clean`, then, if it doesn't help, you'll need to remove `CMakeCache` and regenerate everything (manually!).

If I'm not right about something of the above, please correct me.

I'd like to just do

```
awesome-cmake
```

and have it update everything what needs updating and build the project.

So, the question: is there a way to make "atomic build" with CMake so that it tracks all the required information and abstracts away the usage of `make`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a couple of incorrect ideas here:

> I suspect there may be problems of de-synchronization of CMake files and Makefiles.

Ultimately, CMake is all about producing correct Makefiles (or Visual Studio solution files, or XCode project files, or whatever).  Unless you modify a generated Makefile by hand, there can be no synchronisation issue between CMake and the Makefile since CMake generates the Makefile.

> But then, if you add, say, a new source file to `CMakeLists` and run `make`, it'll be using old `CMakeCache` and `Makefiles` and will not regenerate them automatically.

Actually, the opposite is true: if you modify the CMakeLists.txt (e.g. adding a new source, changing a compiler flag, adding a new dependency) then running `make` will trigger a rerun of CMake automatically.  CMake will read in its previously cached values (which includes any command line args previously given to CMake) and generate an updated Makefile.

> in case something is not building as it should, you'll have to try to perform `make clean`, then, if it doesn't help, you'll need to remove `CMakeCache` and regenerate everything (manually!).

Yes, this would be a pretty normal workflow if something has gone wrong.  However, things don't often get that bad in my experience.

> So, the question: is there a way to make "atomic build" with CMake so that it tracks all the required information and abstracts away the usage of make?

Given that running `make` will cause CMake to "do the right thing", i.e. rerun if required, I guess that using `make` is as close to an "atomic build" as possible.

One thing to beware of here is the use of [`file(GLOB ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/file.html) or similar to generate a list of source files.  From the docs:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

In other words, if you *do* use `file(GLOB ...)` to gather a list of sources, you need to get into the habit of rerunning CMake after adding/removing a file from your source tree; running `make` won't trigger a rerun of CMake in this situation.

Comment: "if you modify the CMakeLists.txt (e.g. adding a new source, changing a compiler flag, adding a new dependency) then running make will trigger a rerun of CMake automatically." 
This pretty much covers the entire question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard workflow for CMake is an out of source build

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to shave off typing out a command, you might be interested in [workflow presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#workflow-preset). You can define a workflow preset that does configuration and build (and more), and then invoke it with [`cmake --workflow ...`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-workflow-preset).

FYI: To build, you can use [`cmake --build ...`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) instead of a specific buildsystem command like `make`. Also, CMake will try to generate buildsystems that detect if the CMake configuration has changed, and rerun CMake configuration first if necessary.